# Selecting GPU over Intel Internal Graphics

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, bios, gpu

I have a Windows 10 PC with an Intel integrated graphics as well as a dedicated GPU.

My display is connected to the GPU but when I boot the PC I get a "No Signal" error message. It eventually goes away and I see the log in screen.

The issue comes when I want to access the BIOS. If I press F2 to access the BIOS I continue getting the black screen, if I then plug in a monitor to the motherboard VGA I can see the BIOS settings but it will not display through the GPU.

In Windows I have disabled the "Generic" Display which the Intel Graphics connects to, I have uninstalled Intel Graphics and have selected to only have the computer display on Display 2. But it still says there are two displays even when only one is connected.

How can I bypass the Intel Graphics entirely and just have the dedicated GPU be used?

I have an adapter plate which means all the plugs from the GPU and motherboard are plugged in and extended but no display is connected to the extender to the motherboard.

Cheers for your help!

Comment: Does BIOS have option to disable on-board or use other external/non-built-in GPU by default? Make and model or motherboard mat be helpful or make and model of the PC if it's not a custom built type.

Comment: Hi, there's no option for that in the BIOS, unfortunately. It's a custom-built PC. I will try to find out the config. Thanks